# Tell modelBuilder not to assume property is an inverse navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Let me try to explain this in a simple manner.

I have this:

```
public class EntityTrackHistory
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
  public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Which is included in my `User` table like this:

```
public class User
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<EntityTrackHistory> Histories { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `EntityTrackHistory` is also included as an `ICollection` on other entities.

Now upon building my database, I get the `*_Id` fields and foreign keys for all those entities which include the `EntityTrackHistory` collection correctly.

However, since one of those tables is `User`, upon creating the database, the model builder thinks the `ModifiedBy` property is the inverse navigation property of the `User` table, and it is not.

One way to solve it is adding a second virtual property to the `User` entity with the `User` name (either using that name or telling `modelBuilder` it is an inverse navigation property):

```
public class EntityTrackHistory
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
  public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

  public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

This works, and EF correctly assumes that `User` is the inverse navigation property and `ModifiedBy` is a different "user".

However, I'm not going to use that navigation property at all (meaning: everytime I access the `EntityTrackHistory`, I'll do it from the original entity), and I want to tell EF that `ModifiedBy` should not be the inverse navigation property.

In my head, the 'solution' does not work because I'm modifiying my entities just to solve some convention on the EF part (my model should be EF-agnostic).

I've found information about how to map properties and navigation properties (or inverse ones, like in this case), but I haven't found information about how to tell EF *NOT* to believe one field is an inverse navigation property just by convention (because of the entity type, in this case).

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the relationship without inverse property specifying the name of the foreign key field:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Histories).WithRequired().Map(m => m.MapKey("User_Id"));
```